# Como desabilitar a edição e bloquear a adição de linhas GridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

Tenho um `GridView` que o usuario entra com algumas informações e salva, gostaria que apôs clicar em salvar. colocar todo grid em modo `ReadOnly` e tambem gostaria de bloquear para inserir ou deletar linhas.

Estou utilizando o ´GridControl` da DevExpress 16.1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui Resolver, editando a propriedade:

```
gridView5.OptionsBehavior.Editable = false;
```

Obrigado.